# How to I change one of my fixed variables to become time dependent?

Tags: python, variables, increment

I have this piece of code that shows a relationship between two objects. The graph usually oscillates at a constant period and amplitude when the system is stable. I would like to be able to have one of the variables constantly increase by a fixed number instead of just having one value. If I could have my beta value increase by say 0.1 each time, the graph's oscillations would increase in amplitude until it balances out. That is the result I would like to achieve. How would I do that?

```py
beta = 1 #growth rate of x-object

# Dynamics of The Model
def f(x, y):
    xdot = x*((beta-tango)-foxtrot*C1-(gamma-delta)*y)
    ydot = y*(-sigma-zeta*C2+(alpha-chi)*x)
```

Comment: Please update your question to show how you call your function. Could the caller supply an updated `beta` value at each call?

Comment: Right now, I can't change the value, but I would like to make it time-dependent. How would I do that?